# How to include a dependency with a classifier in Build.scala

Tags: maven, playframework, dependencies

I'm using the Play Framework for a little project. It has a dependency to a maven package with a classifier like this:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.example.something</groupId>
      <artifactId>something-ejb</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
      <classifier>client</classifier>
</dependency>
```

I want to include this client package... but I have not found a way to tell sbt that I want to have that classifier...

Normally I would add the following:

```
val appDependencies = Seq(
      "org.example.something" % "something-ejb" % "1.0"
)
```

But what then? Where do I include the classifier client?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would take a deep look [into the docs](http://code.google.com/p/simple-build-tool/wiki/LibraryManagement#Classifiers) which looks like this:

```
val testng = "org.testng" % "testng" % "5.7" classifier "jdk15"
```